# How to calculate

Tags: excel

My question is almost identical to this one: [Calculating number of days between two dates dependent on month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179076/calculating-number-of-days-between-two-dates-dependent-on-month)

But I have data that is a rolling 12-months and I need to have additional coding added to the formula:

```
 =IFERROR(IF(AND(MONTH($D2)=F$1,MONTH($E2)=F$1),$E2-$D2,
 IF(MONTH($D2)=F$1,1+EOMONTH($D2,0)-$D2,
 IF(MONTH($E2)=F$1,$E2-DATE(YEAR($E2),F$1,1),
 IF(AND(MONTH($D2)
 F$1,MONTH($E2)>F$1),DAYSINMONTH(DATE(YEAR($D2),F$1,1)),0)))),0)
```

to allow for a reservation that is for February 2018, for example, to show in its own column, and not be included in February 2017.

For example, my data might have:

```
John Smith,  arr 2/21/17  dep 2/18/17
& Matt Jones,  arr 2/21/18  dep 2/18/18
```

and currently the way I have my document built, it would show 2 for column "2", aka February.  I need it to show 1 for Feb-17 and 1 for Feb-18.

Can you help please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to work out what you're looking for but here's what I think you need.

I started from scratch on the formula so I take a different approach to the one in your question.

```
=IF(AND(A3<E3,D3<EDATE(A3,1)),IF(AND(A3>D3,E3>(EDATE(A3,1))),(E3-D3)-((E3-(EDATE(A3,1)))+(A3-D3)),IF(E3>(EDATE(A3,1)),(E3-D3)-(E3-(EDATE(A3,1))),IF(A3>D3,(E3-D3)-(A3-D3),E3-D3))),0)
```

The month that you want to check should be entered as a date, the 1st of the month.

[image: Screenshot]

**How it works**

It's easier to show by example

month to be checked date 01/02/2017

arr date: 27/02/2017
dep date: 02/03/2017

get the end of the month period to be checked date + 1 month EDATE(01/02/2017,1) = 01/03/2017

is the dep date later than the end of the period to be checked? YES

02/03/2017 - 01/03/2017 = 1 (1st value)

get days between arr and dep date 02/03/2017 - 27/02/2017 = 2 (2nd value)

2nd value - 1st value = 1

the example calculation only describes when the arr and dep dates overlap the end of the period to be checked but the formula check for an overlap at the start and also when the entire period to be checked is overlapped and arr date in Jan and dep date in Mar.

The first IF(AND(A3

I hope that explanation helps you to pick the formula apart.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was needing to do - thank you so very much!